# Code counts consonants incorrectly. How to solve this?

Tags: c

I have to write a program that selects consonants from a string and counts them, and shows how many times each of them appeared.
I wrote this code, but it also counts vowels. I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i, consonants;
    i = consonants = 0;
    int freq[256] = {0};

    printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') ||
            (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') &&
            (str[i] != 'a' || str[i] != 'A' ||
             str[i] != 'e' || str[i] != 'E' ||
             str[i] != 'i' || str[i] != 'I' ||
             str[i] != 'o' || str[i] != 'O' ||
             str[i] != 'u' || str[i] != 'U'))
        {
            consonants++;
            freq[str[i]]++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n Number of Consonants in this String = %d", consonants);

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (freq[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("\nThe frequency of %c is %d", i, freq[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is output:

```
Please Enter any String :  We strive to achive peace
Number of Consonants in this String = 21
The frequency of W is 1
The frequency of a is 2
The frequency of c is 2
The frequency of e is 5
The frequency of h is 1
The frequency of i is 2
The frequency of o is 1
The frequency of p is 1
The frequency of r is 1
The frequency of s is 1
The frequency of t is 2
The frequency of v is 2
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a map datastructure

Comment: Note that the opposite of e.g. `str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'E'` is not `str[i] != 'e' || str[i] != 'E'`. If you learn about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) you will instead learn that it's `str[i] != 'e' && str[i] != 'E'`.

Comment: `str[i] != 'a' || str[i] != 'A'`  will always be true.

Comment: Also note that you can simplify your code *very much* by using [the standard classification and conversion functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). Especially look into `isalpha` and `tolower` (or `toupper`).

Comment: On another note, please make it a habit to use *trailing* newlines in your `printf` calls. That will make sure the line is actually written to the terminal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I explained and added corresponding code in my answer. Then I noticed that it is (of course) practically your comment. As far as I know you, you do not mind. Otherwise let me know please.

Comment: @Yunnosch It's okay, I don't mind. I have a tendency to begin writing small comments that turns out to be big and "answery". :)

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to let you know that you can get rid of the huge `if` condition by using the standard functions `isalpha()`, defined in `ctype.h`,  and `strchr()`, defined in `strng.h`.

You can change the whole condition to just

```
if( isConsonant(str[i]) )
```

With `isConsonant()` defined as follows

```
int isConsonant( char c )
{
    static char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";

    if( ialpha(c) && strchr(vowels, c) == NULL ) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice professionally efficient thinking, also (when seen from the point of view of the question) nicely lateral. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This part of your condition (which because of the rest of the logic influences the whole outcome) will always be true:

```
str[i] != 'a' || str[i] != 'A'
```

That is why all letters are counted as consonants.

You want the negation of "is a vowel".

```
!(str[i] == 'a' ||
  str[i] == 'A' ||
  str[i] == 'e' ||
  str[i] == 'E' ||
  str[i] == 'i' ||
  str[i] == 'I' ||
  str[i] == 'o' ||
  str[i] == 'O' ||
  str[i] == 'u' ||
  str[i] == 'U')
```

which is "not(that or that or that)"
or
the logically equivalent
"not that and not that and not that".

```
(str[i] != 'a' &&
 str[i] != 'A' &&
 str[i] != 'e' &&
 str[i] != 'E' &&
 str[i] != 'i' &&
 str[i] != 'I' &&
 str[i] != 'o' &&
 str[i] != 'O' &&
 str[i] != 'u' &&
 str[i] != 'U')
```

Note, I chose to discuss the logic of your code, assuming that it is interesting for you and helpful for your learning. However, I really like the other answer too, which is strong on the wheel-not-inventing philosophy. I won't explain, look there.

Full logic:

```
if ( ( (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') ||
       (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
     )
       /* a letter */
     &&
       /* not a vowel */
     (  str[i] != 'a' && str[i] != 'A' &&
        str[i] != 'e' && str[i] != 'E' &&
        str[i] != 'i' && str[i] != 'I' &&
        str[i] != 'o' && str[i] != 'O' &&
        str[i] != 'u' && str[i] != 'U'
     )
   )
```

Without the additional pair of `()` around "is a letter" you would get
"is a lower case or is an upper case consonant",
i.e. would still be counting lower case vowels.

Comment: This is the code now, but it still doesen't shows correctly
                                                           

if ((str[i]>= 'a' && str[i]<= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') && str[i] != 'a' && str[i] != 'A' && 
str[i] != 'e' &&  str[i] != 'E' &&   str[i] != 'i' &&  str[i] != 'I' && str[i] != 'o' &&  str[i] != 'O' &&  str[i] != 'u' && str[i] != 'U' )

Comment: Try expressing your logic more explicitly, using more `()`. I.e. one pair for "is a letter" and one for "is not a vowel".

Answer (score 0):

You just change

```
||(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
&&(str[i] != 'a' || str[i] != 'A' 
||str[i] != 'e' || str[i] != 'E' 
||str[i] != 'i' || str[i] != 'I' 
||str[i] != 'o' || str[i] != 'O' 
||str[i] != 'u' || str[i] != 'U'))
```

to

```
&&(str[i] != 'a'
&& str[i] != 'A' 
&&str[i] != 'e'
&& str[i] != 'E' 
&& str[i] != 'i' 
&& str[i] != 'I' 
&& str[i] != 'o'  
&& str[i] != 'O'
&& str[i] != 'u' 
&& str[i] != 'U'))
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i=0, consonants=0;
    int vowels=0,numbers=0;
    int freq[256] = {0};

    printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    vowels=0,numbers=0,i=0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {

       if((str[i]>= 'a'&&str[i]<= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')&&(str[i] != 'a' && str[i] != 'A' &&str[i] != 'e'&& str[i] != 'E' && str[i] != 'i' && str[i] != 'I' && str[i] != 'o' && str[i] != 'O'&& str[i] != 'u' && str[i] != 'U'))
      {
         consonants++;
         freq[str[i]]++;
      }
      i++;

   }
   printf("\n Number of Consonants in this String = %d", consonants);

   printf("\n\n");
   for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
   {
       if (freq[i] != 0)
       {
           printf("\nThe frequency of %c is %d", i, freq[i]);
       }
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   return 0;
}
```